# No animation in subview using NavigationStack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, core-data

I have a problem with animations not working when my view is seen from its parent using `NavigationStack`. I have 2 simple views, *parent*:

```swift
struct ListEntitiesView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ListEntity.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default
    )
    private var lists: FetchedResults<ListEntity>
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path.animation()) {
            List {
                ForEach(lists) { list in
                    NavigationLink(value: list) {
                        ListEntityTile(list)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("ListEntities")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    let list = ListEntity(context: viewContext)
                    list.name = "List \(lists.count + 1)"
                    viewContext.forceSave()
                } label: {
                    Label("Add List", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ListEntity.self) { list in
                ListEntityView(list)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and *child*:

```swift
struct ListEntityView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject
    private var list: ListEntity
    @FetchRequest
    private var items: FetchedResults<ListItemEntity>

    init(_ list: ListEntity) {
        _list = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: list)
        _items = FetchRequest(
            fetchRequest: ListItemEntity.fetchRequest(
                of: list,
                sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ListItemEntity.name?.name, ascending: true)]
            ),
            animation: .default
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                ListItemTile(item)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(list.wrappedName)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            NavigationLink {
                AddListItemEntity(list)
            } label: {
                Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListItemTile: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject
    private var item: ListItemEntity

    init(_ item: ListItemEntity) {
        _item = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: item)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            item.flag.toggle()
            viewContext.forceSave()
        } label: {
            Label(item.wrappedName, systemImage: item.flag ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
        }
    }
}
```

In the child Preview, if I create it inside `NavigationStack` everything animates as expected:

```swift
#Preview {
    let list = ListEntity(context: DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
    list.name = "List"
    let name = NameEntity(context: DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
    name.name = "Name"
    let item = ListItemEntity(context: DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
    item.flag = false
    item.list = list
    item.name = name
    DataProvider.shared.viewContext.forceSave()
    return NavigationStack {
        ListEntityView(list)
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
    }
}
```

But once view is inside `NavigationLink` (or created in *parent's* `navigationDestination`) nothing animates:

```swift
#Preview {
    let list = ListEntity(context: DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
    list.name = "List"
    let name = NameEntity(context: DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
    name.name = "Name"
    let item = ListItemEntity(context: DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
    item.flag = false
    item.list = list
    item.name = name
    DataProvider.shared.viewContext.forceSave()
    return NavigationStack {
        NavigationLink {
            ListEntityView(list)
        } label: {
            Text("List details")
        }
    }
    .environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataProvider.shared.viewContext)
}
```

I've found a [thread on Apple's developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/728132), but solution from there doesn't help in my case. Any other ideas? Or maybe my code have a bug in it I don't see?

One thing I discovered is that wrapping button action in `ListItemTile` with `withAnimation` triggers the correct animation, but only as long as `viewContext.foceSave()` is included as well. I also tried to add `.animation(.default, value: item)` property on both, `Button` inside `ListItemTile` and `ItemListTile` itself inside `ListEntityView` to no avail. Shouldn't just wrapping edits to item or adding `.animation` property works? Especially that `Self._printChanges()` shows that item was changed.

I also created minimal example that reproduce my problem. Starting with CoreData model configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="22522" systemVersion="23C71" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" sourceLanguage="Swift" usedWithSwiftData="YES" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="">
    <entity name="ChildEntity" representedClassName="ChildEntity" syncable="YES" codeGenerationType="class">
        <attribute name="flag" optional="YES" attributeType="Boolean" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
        <attribute name="name" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <relationship name="parent" optional="YES" maxCount="1" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ParentEntity" inverseName="childern" inverseEntity="ParentEntity"/>
    </entity>
    <entity name="ParentEntity" representedClassName="ParentEntity" syncable="YES" codeGenerationType="class">
        <attribute name="name" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <relationship name="childern" optional="YES" toMany="YES" deletionRule="Nullify" destinationEntity="ChildEntity" inverseName="parent" inverseEntity="ChildEntity"/>
    </entity>
</model>
```

and whole code example:

```swift
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

class ModelProvider {
    static let shared = ModelProvider()
    private let container: NSPersistentContainer

    var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
        container.viewContext
    }

    private init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Model")
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error {
                fatalError("Could not load persistent stores: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump

        let parent = ParentEntity(context: viewContext)
        parent.name = "Parent"

        let child = ChildEntity(context: viewContext)
        child.name = "Child"
        child.flag = false
        child.parent = parent

        try! viewContext.save()
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ParentEntity.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default
    )
    private var parents: FetchedResults<ParentEntity>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(parents) { parent in
                    NavigationLink(value: parent) {
                        Text(parent.name!)
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                Button {
                    let parent = ParentEntity(context: viewContext)
                    parent.name = "Parent \(parents.count + 1)"
                    try! viewContext.save()
                } label: {
                    Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: ParentEntity.self) { parent in
                ParentDetailView(parent: parent)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ParentDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject
    private var parent: ParentEntity
    @FetchRequest
    private var children: FetchedResults<ChildEntity>

    init(parent: ParentEntity) {
        _parent = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: parent)
        let fetchRequest = ChildEntity.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parent == %@", parent)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ChildEntity.name, ascending: true)]
        _children = FetchRequest(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            animation: .default
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(children) { child in
                ChildTile(child: child)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildTile: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)
    private var viewContext
    @ObservedObject
    var child: ChildEntity

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            child.flag.toggle()
            try! viewContext.save()
        } label: {
            Label(child.name!, systemImage: child.flag ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ParentView()
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, ModelProvider.shared.viewContext)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example So we can try the code without any changes.

Comment: @MatBuompy sure, I edited my question with example. I also added some details I observed during creation of said example.

Comment: Cool. I'll give it a look tomorrow. It's late now in Italy.